# EE TypeError: invalid type (argument="type", value="myEnumName", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.10.0)

Tags: solidity, hardhat, abi

Error occurs during library deployment if I have an enum in function arguments, including structs that have enums. Why does this error happen, and how can I fix it without changing enums to uint8?

`library Query {  function getTripsThatIntersect( address tripServiceAddress, address carServiceAddress, uint64 startDateTime,  uint64 endDateTime   ) public view returns (Schemas.Trip[] memory) {}` // Schemas -> Trip `struct Trip {     //other fields     TripStatus status;`  // <- enum at Array.map () at Function.from node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\fragments .ts:883:69) at Array.map () { code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', argument: 'type', value: 'Schemas.TripStatus', shortMessage: 'invalid type' }

`const Query = await ethers.getContractFactory('Query')   const query = await Query.deploy()`
Library deployment is successful, but I want to know why this error or warning occurs.

Comment: Can you provide an example that produces that error?

Comment: `library Query {

function getTripsThatIntersect(
address tripServiceAddress,
address carServiceAddress,
uint64 startDateTime,
 uint64 endDateTime
  ) public view returns (Schemas.Trip[] memory) {}`
// Schemas -> Trip
`struct Trip {
    //other fields
    TripStatus status;  // <- enum`

    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.from node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\fragments
.ts:883:69)
  
    at Array.map (<anonymous>) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'type',
  value: 'Schemas.TripStatus',
  shortMessage: 'invalid type'
}

Comment: `const Query = await ethers.getContractFactory('Query')
  const query = await Query.deploy()`
Library deployment is successful, but I want to know why this error or warning occurs.

Comment: It will be better if you edit the question to add those details.